# undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

При попытке установить gem fae-rails получаю

```
$ rails g fae:install --trace
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sprockets/digest_utils.rb:47: warning: constant          ::Fixnum is deprecated
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sprockets/digest_utils.rb:51: warning: constant   ::Bignum is deprecated
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:110: warning:    constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:111: warning:constant       ::Bignum is deprecated
Traceback (most recent call last):
-e: undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

Answer (score 1):

У меня проблема решилась понижением версии ruby, а затем я запустил:
gem install rails
bundle install

Comment: и еще одну команду нужно - bundle update actionpack